# Can we define both Bearer token authentication and Basic authentication in a single module of Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a requirement where I have a controller which just needs Basic Authentication, while other controllers need to authenticate via Bearer token. Is it possible in a single module of the Spring Boot application to implement both securities? If yes how should I define it in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, `filters`, and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You would basically implement two different `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s, each configuring their own `HttpSecurity` object and each being applied to distinct sets of requests of your application. Have a look at the following security configuration example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final RequestMatcher BASIC_REQUESTS = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/basic/**");

    private static final RequestMatcher BEARER_REQUESTS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(BASIC_REQUESTS);

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class BasicAuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(BASIC_REQUESTS).authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    ...
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class BearerAuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(BEARER_REQUESTS).authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .addFilter(...)
                    ...
        }
    }

}
```

This tells Spring to handle all requests matching the path `/api/basic/**` with a basic authentication scheme and all other requests with, e.g., a custom filter chain performing some bearer authentication. `HttpSecurity.requestMatcher(...)` makes Spring apply the configuration *only* for requests that match the given request matcher.

Note that you have to manually set an order for your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s because otherwise Spring would try to initialize both beans with the default priority, which would result in a conflict.